# After upgrade to iOS13 beta 6/Xcode 11 beta 5: issue "dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI7BindingVyxGAA0C11ConvertibleAAMc"

Tags: swiftui, xcode11, ios13

After upgrading to iOS13 beta 6 using Xcode 11 beta 5 I receive this message when running on an iPhone SE device.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI7BindingVyxGAA0C11ConvertibleAAMc
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B128240-B05E-4C1C-A0E1-55D22683B49E/BleAdvApp.app/BleAdvApp
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI
 in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B128240-B05E-4C1C-A0E1-55D22683B49E/BleAdvApp.app/BleAdvApp
```

Using the simulator there's no such message, and it has been ok with iOS13 beta 5 on the device, tool 
Compiling is fine, the message is shown at startup of the application on the iPhone with an

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Since there is no Xcode 11 beta 6, the Xcode is still running on beta 5 on MacOS Mojave 10.14.5 (18F132).

I created a simple SwiftUI example from scratch, that's working without any issue on the actual phone and the simulator.

What me also wonders is that there's no path /var/containers on my Mac at all?

Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project folder and deleting your derived data?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57421554/11762053). Are you using `@ObservedObject` anywhere in your app? `@ObservedObject` is currently broken when running an Xcode Beta 5 project on iOS Beta 6.

Comment: @graycampbell I'm not using @ObservedObject, but have two classes conforming to `ObservableObject` and using only @EnvironmentObject. I'll try to find the piece in my code where that symbol `ConvertibleAAMc` is used.

Comment: iOS beta 7 was released today and this problem still exists.

Comment: I have a developer beta 1 Xcode build and developer beta 1 iOS build and it works great, but trying to build from the dev beta 1 Xcode to iOS beta 6 fails with this error every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the update to Xcode 11 beta 6 and using iOS 13 beta 7 the issue does not appear anymore. I used the code posted in the links above.

Answer (score 0):

> SwiftUI APIs deprecated in previous betas are now removed. (52587863)
>
> Several extensions to the Binding structure are removed. (51624798)
>
> The Binding structure’s conditional conformance to the Collection protocol is removed. (51624798)

I believe the answer is this section of release notes. Binding’s removal from conforming to collection.

In a new project utilizing CoreData, crash does not occur. Any other project with dynamic data that is not CoreData, like a set or array crashes with this error.

I followed the migration guide from the notes to account for this removal, but crash still occurs on device. Simulator, previews, etc are all fine.

Comment: I can confirm that the issue occurs in the context of deprecated code which causes the crash: `Toggle(isOn: self.$userData.beacons[self.beaconIndex].isActive) {
                        Text("Active")
                    }
`. Xcode 11 beta 5 gives the following warning message: `'subscript(_:)' is deprecated: See Release Notes for migration path.`.

Comment: The issue is not solved yet. I followed the solutions in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324501/binding-an-element-of-an-array-of-an-observableobject-subscript-is-depre/57333200#57333200] and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57544230/xcode-11-beta-5-subscript-is-deprecated-see-release-notes-for-migratio], the compiler warnings disappear, but the issue exists with the solutions mentioned above. Any further ideas on how to resolve?

Comment: @AnErd, I'm **very** pleased to report that Xcode beta 6 removes the warning!