# SwiftUI dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI7BindingVyxGAA0C11ConvertibleAAMc Xcode 11 beta 5

Tags: xcode, swiftui, dyld, ios13, xcode11

Ever since upgrading to iOS Beta 6 (and Beta 7) I have been unable to launch my SwiftUI app to my iPhone X. The app works fine on iOS Simulator.

Apple's Landmarks tutorial app also fails to boot to my device

I am on the latest version of Xcode (Beta 5)

I am not using any frameworks so this shouldn't be related

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI7BindingVyxGAA0C11ConvertibleAAMc
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/48A73B3C-4DED-46ED-8A93-6DEA1384F3FF/ProduceBuddy.app/ProduceBuddy
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI
 in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/48A73B3C-4DED-46ED-8A93-6DEA1384F3FF/ProduceBuddy.app/ProduceBuddy
```

I have tried re-pairing my device, restarting my computer/phone, cleaning build folder

Comment: Could you try something for me? Create a new app - I'm assuming `LaunchBuddy` is the name of your app. Does it work on your iPhoneX? If not, something is **definitely** wrong. But if it does work? Could you re-introduce code one-by-one (I know, a BIG pain) until you get this error? Right now there's been little here with an error like this and it's difficult to actually duplicate without this sort of effort.

Comment: This [was posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57452325/after-upgrade-to-ios13-beta-6-xcode-11-beta-5-issue-dyld-symbol-not-found?r=SearchResults&s=3|0.0000) a few days ago.

Comment: Do you use `ObservableObject`?

Comment: I created a new app from scratch and it boots to device successfully. Indeed, both my app and Apple's Landmarks tutorial app uses `ObservableObject`

Comment: I have the same problem. For me, the problem occurs when you pass a property of an @EnvironmentObject to a subview, like a Toggle.

Comment: @cbjeukendrup, check out if my answer on this helps you - it seems to work for me:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57511826/change-to-published-var-in-environmentobject-not-reflected-immediately/57513103#57513103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no longer facing this issue upon upgrading to Xcode Beta 6. Thanks for the help everyone!